# How to get mxGraph's/JGraph selected cell including its child elements?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

When we get the selected cells using graph.getSelectionCells(), it returns only the outer cell which is selected, however, I need to get its child elements as well.

The returned cell does not contain its child elements details in it.

Answer (score 5):

Hi Bro Here is sample code which I have vertex containing child elements

```
editor.addAction('delete', function(editor, cell) {
    var cell = graph.getSelectionCell();                    
    console.log(cell);                      
});
```

Cell object contains children I think `cell.children` will return child objects